# Installing Ubuntu Studio on a HP Elitebook

Tags: boot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Studio from usb with Ventoy on it. I've tried every option on the install and it just stops prior to starting the install. I'm stuck. Any Ideas?

Comment: Which model number of Elitebook is it, which CPU and which graphics chip/card?

Comment: 755 G5 AMD Ryzen 7 pro 2700u Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx

Comment: I disabled TPM and it started installing until about half way and it hit a snag and couldn't finish the install. I should of wrote down the snag but frustration got the  better of me and I just pulled out, extended the original partition back to the way it was and re-enabled TPM and all is back to normal, meaning no Ubuntu Studio install. Oh well, I say nice try. If I get a wild hair maybe I'll try again later tonight or tomorrow. Thanks. I'll check back later to see if anyone has any other ideas I can try. :)

Comment: With disabled TPM, does the live session ('Try Ubuntu without installing') work correctly? Please try again and write down any output, 'the snag' and whatever is written, that can help understand what is happening. - You could also try with the [boot options](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `amd_immo=off` and/or `amd.noretry=0`. From the boot menu, press the "E" key. Arrow down to the line that starts with "linux". Add the boot option(s) to end of line. Press "Control+X".

Comment: Update, I was looking for more solutions on the webosphere and downgrading the bios was an option. I had to install the hp software app and after just installing the program I thought what the heck try it now and low & behold the install went like it usually does with no hiccups. Great day A?

Comment: Did you **down**grade the BIOS? That's the first time I read that it helps :-P Anyway, thanks for sharing your solution. You can write an own answer, and after a couple of days 'accept' it in order to make it easy for other users to find your solution.

Comment: Hi sudodus, Well, it ran great until I rebooted. Then it went into a constant reboot loop. I tried everything I could get to fix it and in the end I decided to do the wise thing and just wipe the windows OS and use the entire disk for Ubuntu Studio and all is well now & I never want to deal with windows again lol .